# Gorm one to one relationship based on multiple conditions

Tags: go, orm, go-gorm

I am trying to implement a relationship in GORM that isn't simply based on id foreign key. A quick overview of database structure:

There is an `order` table which contains a `tableNo` column which is generally an integer but can also be a string (some tables are say B2). The table number needs to be matched up to a table (row) in the `table` table (sorry for confusing database table names). This relationship is done through `venueId` and `tableNo`.

If I was to write this relationship in MySQL we could join the tables using the following:

`select o.tableNo, o.venueId, t.title, t.venueId from order o left join table t on t.venueId = o.venueId where replace(t.title, "Table #", '') = o.tableNo  order by o.createdAt desc;`

| tableNo (order) | venueId (order) | title (table) | venueId (table) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 2229 | Table #7 | 2229 |
| 9 | 2462 | Table #9 | 2462 |
| 15 | 2229 | Table #15 | 2229 |

In my model I have written the following:

```
type Order struct {
    Id      int    `json:"id,omitempty"`
    VenueId int    `gorm:"column:venueId" json:"venueId,omitempty"`
    TableNo string `gorm:"column:tableNo" json:"tableNo,omitempty"`
    Table   Table  `gorm:"references:Title,foreignKey:TableNo" json:"table"`
}
```

```
type Table struct {
    Id      int    `gorm:"column:id" json:"id,omitempty"`
    VenueId int    `gorm:"column:venueId" json:"venueId,omitempty"`
    Title   string `gorm:"column:title" json:"title,omitempty"`
}
```

Clearly there are certain things missing, i.e replace on the tableNo in the table model. I also need to connect the table object to the order using the venueId. Gorm currently gives an error `need to define a valid foreign key for relations or it need to implement the Valuer/Scanner interface`  anyway even though the relationship I specified isn't complete.

My current solution is just to manually execute the query as this is what GORM would do anyway with a preload. (i.e order.Table = query_result)

If you have any suggestions as to how to express this relationship in a clean way I would be very grateful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to figure out a solution.

The first main problem was a syntax error which stopped GORM from giving me any query logs. `gorm:"references:Title,foreignKey:TableNo" json:"table"` should have been `gorm:"references:Title;foreignKey:TableNo" json:"table"`

Next I changed the relationship to venueId as thinking back to the SQL this is what the join operation was being made on so we have `gorm:"foreignKey:VenueId;references:VenueId" json:"table"`

Finally the preload had to have a condition included to match the table number value:

`` r.db.Preload("Table", "replace(`table`.title, 'Table #', '') = ?", &order.TableNo).First(&order, id) ``

Now the question is how to not use replace and do this in a way where strings apart from 'Table #' can be in front of tableNo.

Hope someone finds this useful!